# Как заставить слайдер jCarousel автоматически прокручивать слайды?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

Прикрутил к сайту ротатор картинок

Как заставить его менять картинки автоматически, а не только при нажатии на кнопку следующего кадра?

Вот сам код слайдера:

```
function _init_slider1 (carousel) {
    $('#slider_keis .nav_box a').bind('click', function() {
        var index = $(this).parent().find('a').index(this);
        carousel.scroll( index + 1);
        return false;
    });
};

function _active_slide1 (carousel, item, idx, state) {
    var index = idx - 1;
    $('#slider_keis .nav_box a').removeClass('active');
    $('#slider_keis .nav_box a').eq(index).addClass('active');
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slider_keis ul").jcarousel({
        scroll: 1,
        wrap: 'both',
        auto: 0,
        initCallback: _init_slider1,
        itemFirstInCallback: _active_slide1
    });
});
```

Comment: Ищите номер версии jCarousel, которую вы используете! API этого плагина существенно менялся, поэтому без версии ничего конкретного посоветовать нельзя.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function _init_slider (carousel) {
          $('.box_main_nav .inner a').bind('click', function() {
            var index = $(this).parent().find('a').index(this);
            carousel.scroll( index + 1);
            return false;
          });
          $('#main .nav_box a').bind('click', function() {
            var index = $(this).parent().find('a').index(this);
            carousel.scroll( index + 1);
            return false;
          });

          max1 = $('#main .nav_box a').length;
          auto1 = setInterval(function(){
            index = $('#main .nav_box').find('.active').index();
            if(++index == max1){index=0;}
            $('#main .nav_box a').eq(index).click();
          },1000);

        };
```

Comment: а куда этот кусок кода нужно вставить?
у меня в index.html такие кнопки.
     <a href="" class="item1">
     <a href="" class="item2">
     <a href="" class="item3">
     <a href="" class="item4">
     <a href="" class="item5">
и переключение кнопок нужно сделать c помощью if?

Comment: есть возможность показать страничку? более развернуто смогу ответить.
.click() выполняет тоже самое что и клик мыши, но я не вижу что этот плагин делает с dom. поэтому трудно сказать.
http://www.slidesjs.com  я обычно использую этот плагин. 99% задач решает

Comment: вам как то скинуть исходники? вы бы смогли посмотреть?

Comment: выложи на google disk

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_3sh-TwQGPscUdhQlJXSjhVbDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: спасибо большое, теперь все работает! была проблема с версией?

Comment: нет не в версии дело, я просто для одного слайдера добил interval. который раз секунду кликает по следующей кнопке после активного. если вешать на все слайдеры то скопируй код и замени переменные max, auto и селектор в котором находятся кнопки. Если что-то непонятно в моем коде копируй методы в гугл он подробно расскажет что они делают

Comment: спасибо, все более чем понятно.огромная благодарность!

Answer (score 1):

У jCarousel есть плагин, который так и называется [Autoscroll Plugin](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/plugins/autoscroll/). Пример использования и его конфигурацию можно посмотреть [там же](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/plugins/autoscroll/reference/configuration.html).

В вашем случае получится что-то вроде:

```
// Some code here...

$(function(){
    $("#slider_keis ul")
    .on('jcarousel:create', _init_slider1)
    .on('jcarousel:firstin', 'li', _active_slide1)
    .jcarousel({
        wrap: 'both',
    })
    .jcarouselAutoscroll({
        interval: 3000,
        target: '+=1',
        autostart: true
    });
});
```

Comment: у меня это не работает, уже пробовал. тогда перестает работать и вручную - обновляет страницу вместо переключения слайда. говорят из-за старой версии jcarousel

Comment: @Creamov, Autoscroll плагин работает только со свежими версиями, а `jCarousel`, а у @Влад, что-то очень протухшее (`0.1.x` или что-то вроде)...

Comment: @Влад покажите код вашего jCarousel (разместите код на http://pastebin.com или в подобном месте и дайте ссылку) — тогда я напишу вам другое решение, соответствующее вашей версии.

Comment: @Влад или же просто используйте свежую версию [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/), если это допустимо.